# Simpler way to write this

Tags: javascript

Is there a simpler way to write this ugly if/else statement?

It's simply appending a query string to a url depending on whether the variables exist.

```
if (start) {
  url += `?start=${start}`;
  if (end) {
    url += `&end=${end}`;
  }
} else if (end) {
  url += `?end=${end}`;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316781/how-to-build-query-string-with-javascript

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing there is very dangerous. You need to make sure URL parameters are escaped properly, in case they contain special characters (`?`, `&`, `=`, etc.) or characters that are not allowed in URLs.

It would be better to use the existing [URLSearchParams API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) (or a library that provides the same functionality, if the environment doesn't support it, such as Internet Explorer).

```
con urlParams = new URLSearchParams();
if (start) {
  urlParams.append("start", start);
}
if (end) {
  urlParams.append("end", end);
}
console.log("?" + urlParams.toString());
```

Comment: In my case it's not dangerous b/c I left out the security piece. This is just a helper function to build the url. I ended up finding node's `querystring.stringify` method which does exactly what I want https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v10.x/api/querystring.html#querystring_querystring_stringify_obj_sep_eq_options